# Ld: library not found for -lcgraph (QT Application)

Tags: macos, qt

I am currently working on a QT application, however, I am unable to build due to this error which I am unable to resolve. I am currently using macOS Montery and have already installed xcode command line. I have tried searching online and tried many different solutions but to no avail. Any help or advice would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, try the following:

```
brew install graphviz
```